In which case route.id in sveltekit could be null?
VSCode and the typescript definition of the SvelteKit RequestEvent tells me, that route.id could be propably null. I am confuesed of that, because how should it be possible to trigger the hook without calling a route and getting a id for it?

The id can be null if there is no route for a given URL, e.g. if an address is entered directly.
This is probably most relevant for the handle hook which can process any request.

ok that makes sense, this means hook will be called even if there is no route and the default hook will also redirect to 404, but I am able at this moment to do anything else like rediret to the startpage, right?

Yes, you can also directly return a dynamically generated response.
